# Do I use a forward slash or comma for my title and designations?

Tags: commas, slash

Do I use a forward slash or comma for my title and designations? I see both uses throughout my industry but which one is the correct usage, or could both be correct?

Broker/REALTOR®, CRS®, ABR®

Broker, REALTOR®, CRS®, ABR®

Thank you, 
EM

Comment: Very sorry, but, as a policy, we do not proofread on this site. If you have questions about a particular problem in English, please do return and ask.

Comment: @medica “Proofreading questions are off-topic **unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified**” (emphasis added). In practice, we also close questions for this reason if they contain many errors in addition to the specific source of concern, but that doesn’t seem to be a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

According to [REALTOR® Trademark usage FAQ](http://www.realtor.org/letterlw.nsf/pages/TrademarkLogoFAQs):

> The marks should not be used inadvertently and improperly to denote a vocation or business. A good rule to follow is if the term “Member” cannot logically be substituted for the term REALTOR®, then the term should not be used. Appropriate substitutions might include the phrases “real estate broker,” “real estate agent,” “real estate salesperson,” “property manager,” etc.

So, saying you are a REALTOR® is just a more qualified (or precise) way of saying you are a broker, therefore I believe that using the form with the comma would introduce ambiguity. Since a REALTOR® is a type of broker, you could always say "REALTOR® broker" as well, with no comma or slash. The comma would only be useful if it is used in a sentence where you are clarifying what kind of broker you are. Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree with using the slash, but not for the reason you give.  The registered trademarks in the OP indicate not "more qualified" or "precise", but having attained membeship in a recognized body.  In practice, attaining these memberships requires passing tests, demonstrating expertise, and proving experience, but they are association memberships.   In fact, a Realtor can be an agent OR a broker.  And a non-Realtor can be a better agent or broker than someone who has that distinction.

Comment: Just as a clarification, the "more qualified" was in reference to the _way_ of saying it (ie, "a more qualified way of saying X"), not that the person themselves is more qualified.

Comment: Ah ha! Sorry, I was barking up the wrong tree, then! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking when giving ones qualifications, you would separate them by commas.

For example, John Smith, M.D., Ph.D., M.A., B.M.O.C., etc.

Typically when two words are separated by a slash, it is the equivalent of saying *or* aloud.  (Occasionally it is used for *and/or*, too.)

If you are a Broker *or* a REALTOR®, then use a slash.  If you are a Broker *and* a REALTOR®, then use a comma.

A slash isn't technically wrong for *and*, but the use of the comma removes any ambiguity from the equation.